# How do I correct "expected primary-expression before...?"

Tags: c++

I'm just beginning to program and I have no idea what I'm doing. My professor gave us Program Sets to do and I've completed it, but when I Compile the file I get

" J:\Untitled1.cpp In function `int main()':

"36 J:\Untitled1.cpp expected primary-expression before '<<' token "

Here's the full set, remember now that I'm a beginner:

```
/** CONCEPTS PROGRAM #1, TEMPLATE
PROGRAM Name: Yay.cpp
Program/assignment: 
Description: Finds total
Input(s): 
Output(s): 
suffering_with_c++
Date of completion 
*/
//included libraries
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h.>

#define cls system("cls")
#define pauseOutput system("pause")//

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    //variable declaration/initialization
    time_t nowIsTheMoment;
    time(&nowIsTheMoment); 
    string dateTime;//

    cls;
    cout <<"\new live in the moment--only this moment is ours. The Current Date and time is: "
    <<ctime (&nowIsTheMoment); << endl;//
    cout << "\nMy name is Moe Joe." <<endl;//
    cout << endl << "I think Computer Programming with C++ will be a bit more PHUN now!" 
         << endl;
    dateTime = ctime(&nowIsTheMoment);//
    cout << endl << "\nYo ho! I am here now...\n" << endl;
    cout << endl << "The Current Date and time is: "
     <<dateTime <<endl;//
    cout << "\nI know clearly that, if I DO NOT comment my programs/project work thorougly, I will lose substantial points.\n" ;

    cout << "\bHere is Pause Output in action....\n" << endl;//
    pauseOutput; //
    cls;//
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: OMG, my eyes are bleeding! If you simply format this code properly, you will find problem in no time

Comment: Consider formatting your post better.

Comment: My eyes are bleeding, too.  But remove this semicolon: `(&nowIsTheMoment); << endl;`

Comment: The error does not match the source! You quote the error on line 36, but the error is on line 29 of the pasted source.

Comment: Also for the pasted code, the compiler would first complain that it can't find `time.h.`, but you didn't mention anything like that. Next time when you ask about code that does not work, quote both the code and _all_ errors _exactly_. -1 from me for poorly researched question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the semicolon on line 36

```
<<ctime (&nowIsTheMoment); << endl;
                         ^
                         |
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `#include <string>` and qualify `string` and `cout` with `std::`.

Comment: He did not forget to qualify anything. He imported the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Start by removing the `.` after `<time.h>` it should probably help. Then you got this

> ctime (&nowIsTheMoment); << endl;

which can't compile because `<<` needs a left operand (ie: remove the semi-colon).

I don't mean to be rude, but you should try a little bit harder before asking questions on StackOverflow...

Comment: `std::basic_string<CharT, TraitsT>` definitely does have `std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT> &operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT> &, std::basic_string<CharT, TraitsT> const &)` (the template parameters must match).

Comment: Since I am pretty sure about that and checked the documentation too, I'll just delete that wrong section from the question.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, better not confuse anyone.